# Коррекция даты с учетом года

Tags: php, дата

Здравствуйте, подскажите есть ли в PHP какая нибудь умная функция, которая принимала бы в качестве базовой даты строку "**29 dec 2016**" и определяла что строка "**18 jan**" уже 2017 год?

Это работает не так как мне нужно:

```
$date1 = strtotime('29 dec 2016');
$date2 = strtotime('18 jan', $date1);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2);
// 2016-01-18 00:00:00
```

Comment: А почему не напишите сами? Если месяц следующей даты меньше предыдущей, значит другой год. Грубо говоря..... В действительности это не значит что другой год или на год больше предыдущего....но если задача у вас приплюсовать год , то...

Comment: Если "31 dec"? Может, подразумевается 2017 год? А может, "18 jan" - 2020 года? Есть ограничения?

Comment: Написать то можно, но это же надо писать и тестить а вдруг есть решение уже проверенное.
 Нет тут строго есть строчка с текущей датой любая, например 31 dec 2016 и есть строка например 1 jan и  100% понятно что это 1 jan это именно 2017 г.

Comment: А что тестить? решение же простое и железобетонное

Comment: `но это же надо писать` .... действительно. думать еще, ужас же))

Comment: Вообще странная задача что мешает указывать год во втором случае?

Answer (score 3):

Просто проверить не меньше ли текущей даты 18 января и прибавить год.

```
$date1 = strtotime('29 dec 2016');
$date2 = strtotime('18 jan', $date1);
if ($date1 > $date2) {
    $date2 = strtotime('+1 year', $date2);
}
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2);
// 2017-01-18 00:00:00
```

Comment: Да, сработает, останется 2016 год. Поправил сравнение дат, сравнивал с текущим

Comment: Так делал раньше, но был какой то подвох и не могу вспомнить какой. Спасибо буду пока это юзать)